# Images / files in different folders faster?

Tags: php, html, apache

at the moment I have a image gallery with arround 10k jpg files. They are all in the "upload" folder. Is it for speed issues better to store them in different folders for example Year / Month or it doestn matter for the apache, html and php?

I like the folder structure more but its a lot of work and when the speed is the same I will not work on this.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with faster? Are you storing file informations in mysql?

Comment: No it isn't. Probably your directory will be indexed. I would only take a look at it if you have thousands of files.